# After clicking. A function is called multiple times ... Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay friends. I need your thought here. The code has two simple
actions. The first action adds ADD after the click. Second action
Click X with any number. Now that a second action is called. The code
should only be printed once! What a worker does not read has a call of
several times! Can anyone explain why?

I took the same code .... with another HTML code with 3 DIV that
already exist. And the code works fine.

```js
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    $("#items").append('<div><input/><button class="btn_x">X' + count + '</button></div></br>');
    count++;

    $(".btn_x").on("click", function() {
      console.log($(this).html());
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="items"></div>
```

Comment: I haven't use jquery in a long time, but if i'm not mistaken, everytime on is called, it adds a new callback to the event. Try one instead of on: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding a new event listener every time you click `#add`. Instead, you could just listen to events on the parent element and capture elements from the child elements.

```js
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    $("#items").append('<div><input/><button class="btn_x">X' + count + '</button></div></br>');
    count++;
  });
  
  // Listen to events on the parent element
  $("#items")
    // But only capture events from child elements with .btn_x
    .on("click", ".btn_x", function() {
      console.log($(this).html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="items"></div>
```

You can think of it this way: every time an event happens on a `.btn_x`, it's going to tell `#items` about it. Whenever `#items` hears about it, it lets you handle the event just like if you were listening to `.btn_x` directly.

The problem with your approach was every time you clicked `#add` you were saying "every single one of you .btn_x's! Here's a new event handler for you!".

Comment: He's not clicking on `#items` element though, he's clicking on the `#add` button. `#items` is not a parent element here

Comment: @taylorc93 Read the description of the problem. The problem is that when they click on `X1`, `X2`, etc. they're getting multiple responses. That's because the `#add` click handler is adding extra event handlers that shouldn't be there. Handling the event on `#items` allows them to capture events from *any* `.btn_x` element without binding to it directly.

Comment: Wow thanks .
The answer is really well explained!
Just short and to the point!
Thank you!

Comment: @L.Shabtai Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a listener for every `btn_x` item instead of adding a listener to only the newly created item. Try changing the classname to something like `btn_1`, `btn_2`, etc:

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    var buttonClass = ".btn_" + count;
    $("#items").append('<div><input/><button class="' + buttonClass + '">X' + count + '</button></div></br>');
    count++;

    $(buttonClass).on("click", function() {
      console.log($(this).html());
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to reply.
But I do not want to change the class.
I need everyone in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are asking, but this may be helpful.

```js
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    $("#items").empty().append('<div><input/><button class="btn_x">X' + count + '</button></div></br>');
    count++;
  })
  $(".btn_x").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="items"></div>
```

Comment: They don't want only one item, they want multiple ones. This also doesn't handle the `.btn_x` binding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a double call in case of #add or #item. Your listener function call both of them.when you want to call only one. 
Must check your code again. I hope you got my point.